# Display notifications on a particular time

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I would like to display notification on a particular time and daily routine (i.e at 8'o clock morning). I am using broadcast receiver, alarmmanager to display notifications. 
But the problem is, I am not getting the notifications displayed on mobile.
I've added wake lock permissions in manifest file also. Help me please
Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent notificationmassage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationClass.class);

  //This is alarm manager
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0 , notificationmassage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
          AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

  Toast.makeText(this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

NotificationClass.java

```
public class NotificationClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                                .setContentTitle("Text1")
                                                .setContentText("Text2 ");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager ;
        mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".NotificationClass">
        </receiver>
</application>
```

UPDATE: - now the issues was when ever I open the Application notification arises. For Ex: Alarm Set to 8.AM, whenever I open the app after 8 AM,the notification arises..even though the current time is > 8 AM. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity Replace following

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notificationmassage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationmassage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Okay. .It is showing notification when I open the application. When I close the application it will not showing it. I think it is not running in background as a process

Comment: How do I run it as background process.. So that it will display notifications on particular time even my application is closed?

Comment: you are using AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Therefore once you call am.setRepeating(...) it should wake the device at desired time Automatically and with implementation of your Receiver it should display notification.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you..It's working now. But the one issues was, when ever I **open** the Application notification arises.  For Ex: Alarm Set to **8.AM**, whenever I have **open** the app **after 8 AM**,the notification arises..even though the current time is > 8 AM. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void getNotification(Context context,String Message){     
          int icon = R.drawable.appicon;
            int when =(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, Message, when);

            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
             notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title,Message, intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            // Play default notification sound
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification); 

    }
```

Comment: I want to display notification on a particular time on a daily basis or a routine like @8'o clock in the morning. How to do that?

Comment: How do I run it as background process.. So that it will display notifications on particular time even my application is closed?